# can I use a 12v car battery to connect to a L298N h-bridge to control two 12v dc motor

Tags: pi-4, battery, voltage, dc-motor, current

I am new to the raspberry pi world and electronic in general. so I am wondering if it is safe to hook up 20 AWG wires to a car battery and have those wires going into a L298N h-bridge to power 2 AUTOTOOLHOME 6-12V Mini DC Motor also using 20 AWG. All which is used by the raspberry pi 4 to control the speed and direction of the motor. Is this possible and safe to use a car battery? Is 20AWG ok to use on a battery that size, do I need resistors, capacitors or something else? any type of information would help

The motor I am using: [https://www.amazon.com/AUTOTOOLHOME-Torque-Traxxas-Wheels-Electric/dp/B01M58POHF/ref=sr_1_2?crid=3636FZD5UVI2Z&keywords=dc+motor&qid=1648526936&sprefix=dc+moto%2Caps%2C121&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M58POHF)

The H-Bridge I am using: [https://www.amazon.com/HiLetgo-Controller-Stepper-H-Bridge-Mega2560/dp/B07BK1QL5T/ref=sr_1_4?crid=2H75IA51OX5V4&keywords=h+bridge+12v&qid=1648524612&sprefix=h+bridge+12v%2Caps%2C89&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BK1QL5T)

The car battery is a 12v 600CCA CA750 RC110

Comment: define `safe` ... powering a 12 V device from a car battery is safe for the device ... the battery can provide enough current to vaporize wires if you happen to short something

Answer (score 1):

If you wire it up correctly it is safe.

Note that the L298N module can only provide a couple of amps of current.

You do not need additional components other than wire.

Comment: Completely true. To be safe that the signal is clean you 'could' add an extra filtering capacitor (electrolytic) in parallel to your battery (the bigger, the better). In my experience 12V lead acid batteries have a pretty rough signal. Especially if you would also like to power low voltages signals (like the RPi uses) through a car battery. If your are only going to use the car battery to power the `L298N` through the battery, then you'll probably be fine without.

Comment: @MatsdeWaardM `lead acid batteries have a pretty rough signal` are you talking about the battery, or about automobile power?